# why does gpsd not update a location past its first fix?

Tags: pi-zero, raspberry-pi-os, gps, bugs

I'm running GPSD 3.23.1 built from source but this also occurred on GPSD 3.22-4 from the debian/raspbian repositories.

When I launch any gpsd client, gpsd sends the first fix it managed to acquire, and then sends nothing else. Two fixes for this are running `ubxtool -p RESET` or unplugging, then replugging the gps mouse, however neither of these persist past a restart of the daemon.

The GPS mouse is not broken as it works just fine on other devices running gpsd and on gpsmon.

The only other case of this that I could find online is on [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/qg64n2/kali_kismet_and_a_gps_dongle_that_doesnt_want_to/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and updating gpsd to version 3.25 solved the issue. I followed [these instructions](https://austinsnerdythings.com/2021/10/01/how-to-update-gpsd-by-building-from-source/) that I found in the comments of the [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/qg64n2/kali_kismet_and_a_gps_dongle_that_doesnt_want_to/) you pointed to.

**TL;DR**

```bash
sudo apt install -y scons \
  libncurses-dev python-dev pps-tools git-core asciidoctor python3-matplotlib\
  build-essential manpages-dev pkg-config python3-distutils

wget http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/gpsd/gpsd-3.25.tar.gz
tar -xzf gpsd-3.25.tar.gz
cd gpsd-3.25/

sudo scons
sudo scons install
sudo reboot
```

Note: This won't setup the system's service as it would by installing gpsd with `sudo apt install gpsd gpsd-clients`, so you have to start it manually using: `sudo gpsd --nowait --badtime --speed 9600 /dev/ttyACM0` (adjust the parameters for your setup).

Comment: I'll mark this answer as accepted once I'm able to test this. Thanks for the system service extra info, I missed that in my earlier research.

Comment: This worked for me, however for some reason the GPSD service was not running the new version. So make sure that `/usr/sbin/gpsd` is the proper binary. In my case I had to copy the 3.25 one from `/usr/local/sbin`. My best guess is that it wasn't updated because the service was running when it should have been replaced? Either way, replacing it makes everything work.